# How to tell my django template where static file (dajax.core.js) is?

Tags: python, django, templates

I'm trying to use [Dajax](http://dajaxproject.com/) in my Django app, but I'm getting a 404 Error when I try to include it in my html template. I've installed both Dajax and Dajaxice on Windows 7. Here's what my STATIC_URL looks like:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

My static folder is placed in my app's folder, so from the src folder in my Eclipse project, the static folder's path is:

```
appname/static
```

I've placed the following javascript files into a 'js' directory within my static directory:

```
dajaxice.core.js
jquery.dajax.core.js
```

Within the head tag in my template is my script tag that looks like this:

```
<script src="{{ STATIC_URL }}js/jquery.dajax.core.js" type="text/javascript" charset="UTF-8"></script>
```

However, when I open my template, I get the following error:

```
GET http://localhost:8000/dajax/js/jquery.dajax.core.js 404 (NOT FOUND)
```

Why is jquery.dajax.core.js not being found? Thanks for your help!

**EDIT** Also, here's what my view looks like:

```
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from django.template import RequestContext

def dajax(request):
    return render_to_response('dajax.html', context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

It's very simple because I'm just testing things out.

Comment: do you handle `/static/` in your urls.py?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would assume it's because you need add the static server for django (which is only used for running locally)

add this to your urls.py:

```
if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += patterns('',
        (r'^static/(.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve', {'document_root': settings.STATIC_PATH}),
    )
```

or you need to point `MEDIA_ROOT` at the absolute path to your static folder.

otherwise, i'd guess you are declaring your `STATIC_URL` twice in your settings, because you say you set it to `/static/` , but then template seems to be replacing it with `dajax`

ie `GET http://localhost:8000/dajax/js/jquery.dajax.core.js 404 (NOT FOUND)`

should be `http://localhost:8000/static/js/jquery.dajax.core.js`

Comment: I checked my settings.py file, and I'm only setting STATIC_URL once. I also added that snippet to my urls.py code, and I still get the same error. Would it help if I just uploaded my app for you to look through? I'm only running this locally through the django runserver, so it would be easy to move over to another environment.

Comment: I'm such a noob. I didn't have my app included in the INSTALLED_APPS tuple in settings.py. Adding that fixed my problem. Also, static files work without adding the static pattern.